# Is it possible to determine Collection Date of ESRI World Imagery Basemap

Tags: imagery, arcgis-online-basemaps

It seems like it was possible to do this with Google Imagery if I recall but is there any way to determine the date of collection of Esri's World Imagery basemap (or other basemaps) at a given location?

Something I read indicated that this was updated Sept, 2014 but I don't think that has anything to do with the date of collection.

I have been telling people that it is 2014 Imagery but I've been challenged on that statement because features on the landscape are showing up that have reportedly been removed.

The basemap I'm most interested in knowing about is [World_Imagery (MapServer)](http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer).

Comment: is there a plus next to your imagery layer in arcmap? in 10.2 there is and when you expand that you see that the citation is defaulted off. When you turn it on it automatically places citation in the bottom of the data frame.

Comment: To the answer above (I can't comment due to lack of points), I would point out that when I zoom in and the aerial image changes, the date doesn't change, so that is not necessarily accurate.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/113037)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with the [Identify](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000010000000) tool, just use it to click the World Imagery layer and it will tell you a few things about the imagery, including the date it was collected:

[image]

[image: Citation]

Comment: Oh Sweet. I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: @jbchurchill sure, no problem. FYI, a lot of the imagery in the World Imagery layer is available from other sources, like the National Map Viewer and often state and local governments. If you want to be absolutely sure of the photo capture date you may want to try to track down the same imagery through other sources, where you may find metadata.

Answer (score 1):

I developed an app that loads the extents and acquisition dates of Esri World Imagery, see here : https://martinedoesgis.github.io/esri-imagery-date-finder/app.html

Answer (score 0):

Also this is possible in a browser (use `identify` tool). URL: [ArcGIS World Imagery](https://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?useExisting=1&layers=10df2279f9684e4a9f6a7f08febac2a9)

[image]