# Creating polygons of Esri World Imagery Basemap that shows collection date

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.5, imagery, arcgis-online-basemaps

I'm working with the Esri World Imagery Basemap, and I need to determine the imagery collection date for every portion of my area of interest.

I'm aware that the identify tool displays the collection date of the imagery at a specific point (briefly showing the area of the imagery). However, I want to simultaneously view the collection dates for all the areas within my region of interest. I came across an excellent online application that provides this functionality [here](https://martinedoesgis.github.io/esri-imagery-date-finder/app.html), posted in this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/337560/216733), but I want to have the polygons layer to work directly in ArcMAP. Nevertheless, I prefer to work directly in ArcMAP and would like to have access to the polygons layer. My current version of ArcMAP is 10.8.

How can I achieve this?